# What is the difference between the Mogensen-Scott and the Boehm-Berarducci encoding for ADTs on the Lambda Calculus?

Tags: functional-programming, lambda-calculus

On the Lambda Calculus, there are several different ways to represent a list. For example, one can encode it as its right fold:

```
list = (λ (cons nil) (cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 nil))))
```

One can, instead, use `pair`, `false`, `fst` and `snd` as aliases to `cons`, `nil`, `head` and `tail`. This way, you will have this:

```
list = (λ (a) (a 1 (λ (b) (b 2 (λ (c) (c 3 0))))))
```

Another way is to use the Mogensen-Scott encoding, which represents a list as the `case` statement required to deconstruct it:

```
list = (λ (c n) (c 1 (λ (c n) (c 2 (λ (c n) (c 3 (λ (c n) n)))))))
```

But there is also another way, called Boehm-Berarducci encoding, which I didn't understand. Supposedly, it allows the same thing that the Scott allows: systematically representing ADTs with lambda terms. So, what is the difference?

Comment: "Boehm-Berarducci encoding" is another way to tell "right fold". For list it's `list = (λ (c n) (c 1 (c 2 (c 3 n))))`, i.e. your first example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Boehm–Berarducci encoding is often mistakenly referred to as the "Church" encoding. They both start from the same general idea (encode data types by their iterator/catamorphism), but differ in subtle ways. In particular, the Church encoding only represents data types in the untyped setting, only covers introduction, and is not tight; whereas, the Boehm–Berarducci encoding works in System F, covers both introduction and elimination, and proves that the encoding is tight.

For an extensive discussion of the differences, see [this post by Oleg Kiselyov](http://okmij.org/ftp/tagless-final/course/Boehm-Berarducci.html).

Comment: What is meant by "tight"?

Comment: By "tight" was probably meant that principal type of an encoded expression is enough, and there is no need to restrict it more.